# JSOUP find identical tag elements that are not separated by other tags

Tags: java, html, spring, jsoup

Code example:

```
<body>
    <p>123124</p>
    <p>214565</p>
    <p>123333</p>
    <img src = "aboba"/>
    <p>faaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaa</p>
    <a href="src"></a>
    <p>1111</p>
</body>
```

Using jsoup to wrap in `<div class="test"></div>`

I expect that it will turn out something like that

Result:

```
<div class="test">
    <p>123124</p>
    <p>214565</p>
    <p>123333</p>
</div>
<img src = "aboba"/>
<div class="test">
    <p>faaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaa</p>
</div>
<a href="src"></a>
<div class="test">
    <p>1111</p>
</div>
```

UPDATE: correction of the expected result

Comment: why do you want to do this? why not write the html how you want it in the first place?

Comment: If there is only single `<p>` element, do you also want to surround it in `<div class="test">`?

Comment: @Pshemo Yes, that's right

Comment: @lance-java I need to process the html, not write it myself.

Comment: Then your title is misleading since it claims you want to surround only *identical* elements. If there is only one `<p>` there is no *other* identical element so according to this rule it shouldn't be surrounded (just like `<img>` element is not surrounded in posted example).

Comment: @Pshemo I have edited the example and the result for a better understanding

Answer (score 2):

> *"... find identical tag elements that are not separated by other tags ..."*

You can use a *[ListIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html)* to mutate an *[Elements](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html)* collection.
Additionally, you can utilize the *[next](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html#next())* and *[previous](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html#previous())* methods to adjust the iterator's cursor.

Here, the *element* and *next* variables hold the current and following elements, respectively.

The concept is to add all *p* elements to the new *div* element.
The *div* is only added when the *next* element is *null* or not a *p* element.

```java
String string
  = "<body>\n" +
    "    <p>123124</p>\n" +
    "    <p>214565</p>\n" +
    "    <p>123333</p>\n" +
    "    <img src = \"aboba\"/>\n" +
    "    <p>faaaa</p>\n" +
    "    <p>aaaaa</p>\n" +
    "    <a href=\"src\"></a>\n" +
    "    <p>1111</p>\n" +
    "</body>";
Document document = Jsoup.parse(string);
Elements body = document.select("body").first().children();
ListIterator<Element> iterator = body.listIterator();
Element element, next, div = new Element("div").attr("class", "test");
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    element = iterator.next();
    if (element.tagName().equalsIgnoreCase("p")) {
        div.appendChild(element);
        iterator.remove();
    }
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        next = iterator.next();
        iterator.previous();
        if (!next.tagName().equalsIgnoreCase("p")) {
            iterator.add(div);
            div = new Element("div").attr("class", "test");
        }
    } else {
        iterator.add(div);
    }
}
```

Here is the output for *body*.

```html
<div class="test">
 <p>123124</p>
 <p>214565</p>
 <p>123333</p>
</div>
<img src="aboba">
<div class="test">
 <p>faaaa</p>
 <p>aaaaa</p>
</div>
<a href="src"></a>
<div class="test">
 <p>1111</p>
</div>
```